# Cast camera and mic from mobile device (Android or iOS)

Tags: android, ios, camera, microphone, chromecast

Is there an app that will enable casting (to a TV in another room on the same WiFi network in our case, but that's not relevant) of both the camera view and the mic's audio? Imagine casting from a camcorder - that's what I'm after. If bandwidth on WiFi is an issue, I don't care if the resolution is lower (720p or even SD) as long as the frame rate is reasonable and the sound is included.

Scenario: I have a Smart TV in one room on which I want to show the scene (including audio) of what is going on in the neighboring room, live. (The feed can lag behind reality a few seconds, but the video and audio need to be in sync with each other - this is for nursing moms to watch a small church's worship service). I don't care what kind of device I use as the camera, but I'd like to only have to mess with two devices (the "camera" and the TV, not an additional PC or phone between the two). I first thought I'd use a real IP camera, but I can't find one that doesn't require a proprietary app on the viewing device. Even one that claimed to support viewing on an ordinary browser turned out to require the company's special ActiveX-based plugin (and therefore only IE), a no-go on a TV. Phones cast nicely over WiFi to ChromeCast, FireTV, or whatever, so I thought maybe a cheap used phone could be used as the camera, but trying on my own Android phone, I can't get the mic's audio to cast (another problem is that the camera app times out after awhile if not recording, but that might be fixed with a setting or a different app). I don't mind using a separate mic connected to the phone if that helps, but the point is that the sound in the room needs to be cast over WiFi along with the visual. Also, it needs to work without the cloud - the rooms have a WiFi LAN but not internet.

It seems like a simple idea for an app - just turn on the camera and mic and allow normal casting of the data they are gathering... but does such an app exist? (Ideas of other ways to do this are also welcome.)

Answer (score -1):

Buy a cheap hikvision dvr that takes audio.

You don't even need a harddrive.

Then use their app (if its the same network works on real time).

I don't know if your smart tv lets you install any app though.